# Problema al validar imagen con Request

Tags: laravel-5, laravel

estoy desarrollando en Laravel 5.1 y estoy teniendo un pequeño problema al momento de validar un formulario, estoy usando Request para esto, las reglas que tengo son las siguientes:

**ProductoCreateRequest**

```
public function rules()
{
    return ['nombre'        =>   'required|max:50',
            'presentacion'  =>   'required',
            'unidad'        =>   'required',
            'codigo'        =>   'required|numeric|max:4',
            'almacen'       =>   'required',
            'categoria'     =>   'required',
            'pathImg'       =>   'image',
    ];
}
```

El problema aquí es que la imagen me la esta tomando como que es requerida, lo que busco es que solo valide al momento que se subió un archivo, si no se sube nada entonces que no marque el error de que necesita ser una imagen, así como también en *codigo*, mi validación es que máximo sea de 4 dígitos, pero siempre me marca error cuando escribo menos de estos, solo me permite 1 digito,al escribir 2 o 3 igual me marca ese error.

Agredecería su ayuda.

Answer (score 0):

Si deseas que el campo sea validado como imagen solo si se subió algún archivo, entonces puedes utilizar `sometimes`, dicha regla solo valida en caso que haya algo en dicho campo:

```
'pathImg' => 'sometimes|image',
```

Puedes ver más información aquí: https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/validation#conditionally-adding-rules

Comment: Hola, gracias por responder, tal vez no me explique muy bien, ese campo no debe de ser requerido, solo debe de validarse que el archivo que se subió sea una imagen y mi problema es que me esta marcando que debe ser una imagen aunque no suba nada de archivo.

Comment: Ok, entonces es mucho más sencillo, ya voy a editar la respuesta.

Comment: Muchisimas gracias amigo.

Comment: Si la respuesta te sirvió, puedes marcarla como aceptada.

Comment: No me funciono, me sigue marcando como obligatoria y ahora tengo otro poblema, en codigo tengo la validación de  max:4 y si escribo 4 caracteres me marca error, igual con 3 y 2, solo me permite escribir un digito.

Comment: Si lees la documentación de Laravel, te darás cuenta que estás usando `max` de forma incorrecta: https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/validation#rule-max

Answer (score 0):

Para validar el código usa digits:

```
//,
'codigo' => 'required|digits:4'
//,
```

Para la validación quiza debas hacerlo en el controlador, podría tratarse de algún error de la versión 5.1 y 5.2 ya que a partir de Laravel 5.3 se incluyo la regla `nullable` con la cual podrías hacer algo como:

```
//,
'pathImg' => 'nullable|image',
//,
```